# Capture derivative of an intermediate pipeline result while running rest of pipeline as well

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a bunch of  `*.bz2` files containing some compressed text data. I decompress them into a single file `intermediary.txt` to count the occurrences of the substring `myString`:

```
find . -name '*bz2' -exec bzip2 -k -c -d {} > intermediary.txt
```

and then (to count the number of occurrences of `myString`)

```
echo "Number of occurrences:"
grep -o "myString" intermediary.txt | wc -w
```

Processing then continues by some stream manipulations:

```
cat intermediate.txt | sed ... | sed ... | someCommand > out.txt
```

I now want to process all the steps in one pipeline, i.e. have the result in `out.txt` and still have the number of occurrences of `myString` on stdout without having to write `intermediary.txt`. So the pipeline should look something like this:

```
find . -name '*bz2' -exec bzip2 -k -c -d {} | <some magic here> | sed ... | sed ... | someCommand > out.txt
```

(How) Is that possible?

**UPDATE**
I tried out @Charles Duffy's version below, but modified the `bzip2`-part a bit to use `bzcat` instead. I think it's a bit less verbose and it should not affect performance (not sure though).

This gets the job done. However, it would be nice now to include this pipeline in [Pipeline Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to get some feedback about the progress (there are a lot of `*.bz2` files!). Prefixing the whole thing with `pv -cN source < ...` does not work. I posted a separate question for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482820/use-pipeline-viewer-to-show-progress-for-uncompression-of-a-list-of-processed-fi)

Comment: Use [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)

Comment: Have a look at `bzgrep`

Comment: As an aside, `find -name` is less portable than `find . -name`; the ability to leave out a starting directory name is a GNU extension.

Comment: What's the point of `!` here? The way I read the question you don't want to invert any of the operators.

Comment: Acknowledged (both, the missing `.` and the `!`). The `.` was lost and the `!` accidentally inserted while writing a simplified (abstract) version of the actual pipeline. I updated the code in the question accordingly. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I also believe that the full pipeline and grep could be replaced by a single `awk`

Comment: BTW, consider posting your own answer (flagged community-wiki if you don't think there's enough new content to be worth getting rep for it) rather than editing answer-related content into the question. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fewer complications to keep what you're capturing as the stdout of the end of the pipeline, and use a process substitution for other outputs:

```
result=$(find . -name '*bz2' -exec bzip2 -k -c -d {} + \
          | tee >(sed ... | sed ... | someCommand >out.txt) \
          | grep -e myString \
          | wc -l)
```

Note the use of `-exec ... {} +`, which is significantly more efficient than the `find` operation you were using before (which ran a separate copy of `bzip2` for each output file).

Comment: I tried this out (with modifications) and it seems to work. Thanks for that. Now it would be nice to integrate it with [Pipeline VIewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml). I think it's only a small step from here, but I can't get it to work. I updated the question accordingly. I know it's not part of the original question anymore but it would still be nice if you could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: We'd really need a lot more definition about *how* you wanted to use `pv` here. If you wanted a proper percentage dialog based on number of files processed, we'd need to generate the full list of files (so we knew how many there were) before we started processing any of them; that would mean we'd be starting later, since we couldn't decompress as soon as we found the first file. Similarly, to get a percentage based on number of lines, we'd need to count the total lines.

Comment: Getting `pv` to emit only a *rate* (of files processed, or lines, or what-have-you) would be easier, but either way, we're in a place where there are enough details that need to be specified that a distinct question is called for.

Comment: You're right. I'm marking your answer as the right one and removed the code snippet in my question. I opened a new question for the problem with the Pipeline Viewer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482820/use-pipeline-viewer-to-show-progress-for-uncompression-of-a-list-of-processed-fi)

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirection and `tee`:

```
#! /bin/bash
exec 3>&1
echo $'a\nd\nc\nb' | tee >(wc -w >&3) | sort > output
```

The output of `echo` goes into two streams, one is processed by `wc` and goes to &3, which is shown on output. The other one is further processed by `sort` and saved into the `output` file.