# Use Pipeline Viewer to show progress for uncompression of a list of processed files

Tags: bash, progress-bar, pipeline

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480291/capture-derivative-of-an-intermediate-pipeline-result-while-running-rest-of-pipe).

I have a list of compressed `*.bz` files whose content I push through a pipe as follows:

```
result=$(find . -name '*bz2' -exec bzcat {} + \
        | tee >( some | other | pipeline ) \
        | grep -e "myString" \
        | wc -l)
echo "${result} occurrences found"
```

This will process the decompressed contents of the files with a sub-pipeline `(some | other | pipeline)` and at the same time count and return the occurrences of the string `myString`.

The pipeline works but now I want to display a progress bar using [Pipeline Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml). The progress should be shown as the number of already processed `*.bz2` files.

Comment: Hmm. *Processed*, not *found*? Might need to slow down the processing to get that number right, as by running one `bzcat` per file. With `-exec ... {} +` or `xargs -0` with no `-n`, processing happens in large batches, without feedback about where files are within that batch.

Comment: Where are the bottlenecks here, where we really need accurate measurement? Is `some | other | pipeline` slow to start up? Is it slow to execute, once it's run? Is the cost of rerunning that pipeline on a per-file basis acceptable, if we were to do so? Or is the `find` one of the biggest costs? And how large *is* the number of files? Is it huge enough that the batching might manage to disappear into the averages?

Comment: I am pretty sure the bottleneck is in `(some | other | pipeline)` where the last command is executing a Python command. This turns out more complicated than I thought. I think for now its enough to shove `| pv \` as the second step in the main pipeline to show the rate (and that something is happening). Thanks though.

Comment: I'd consider putting the `pv` *after* the `xargs -0 bzcat` but before the `tee`, so you're showing the rate of lines being processed, vs the rate of files being processed; if the goal is to show progress, that will lead to a smoother / less "chunky" display.

Answer (score 0):

If you care more about measuring the speed of `find` than the speed of the other components (which will eventually exhibit backpressure and slow the measured components down, but this may happen with more lag than you'd like without performance impeded by a smaller `-n` argument added to `xargs`):

```
result=$(find . -name '*bz2' -print0 \
        | pv -0 --line-mode \
        | xargs -0 bzcat \
        | tee >( some | other | pipeline ) \
        | grep -e "myString" \
        | wc -l)
echo "${result} occurrences found"
```